# VTK - create 3D model

Tags: vtk

I'm trying to create a 3D mask model from the 3D coordinate points that are stored in the txt file. I use the Marching cubes algorithm. It looks like it´s not able to link individual points, and therefore holes are created in the model.

Steps: (by https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Modelling/MarchingCubes/)

First, load 3D points from file as vtkPolyData.

Then, use vtkVoxelModeller

Put voxelModeller output to MC algorithm and finally visualize

[visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxCAr.png)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The example takes a spherical mesh (a.k.a. a set of triangles forming a sealed 3D shape), converts it to a voxel representation (a 3D image where the voxels outside the mesh are black and those inside are not) then converts it back to a mesh using Marching Cubes algorithm. In practice the input and output of the example are very similar meshes.

In your case, you load the points and try to create a voxel representation of them. The problem is that your set of points is not sufficient to define a volume, they are not a sealed mesh, just a list of points.

In order to replicate the example you should do the following:

1) building a 3D mesh from your points (you gave no information of what the points are/represent so I can't help you much with this task). In other words you need to tell how these points are connected between then to form a 3D shape (vtkPolyData). VTK can't guess how your points are connected, you have to tell it.

2) once you have a mesh, if you need a voxel representation (vtkImageData) of it you can use vtkVoxelModeller or vtkImplicitModeller. At this point you can use vtk filters that need a vtkImageData as input.

3) finally in order to convert voxels back to a mesh (vtkPolyData) you can use vtkMarchingCubes (or better vtkFlyingEdges3D that is a very similar algorithm but much faster).

Edit:
It is not clear what the shape you want should be, but you can try to use vtkImageOpenClose3D so the steps are:

First, load 3D points from file as vtkPolyData.

Then, use vtkVoxelModeller

Put voxelModeller output to vtkImageOpenClose3D algorithm, then vtkImageOpenClose3D algorithm output to MC (change to vtkFlyingEdges3D) algorithm and finally visualize

Example for vtkImageOpenClose3D:
https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/ImageOpenClose3D

Comment: 1) The mask consists of contours (like CT slices) and each contour contains list of 3D points.

Comment: You probably want to try MeshLab, it has some surface reconstruction features that should do what you need (try surface reconstruction: pivoting ball and play with parameters). To do it with VTK - take no offense - you would need to read this: https://www.vtk.org/vtk-textbook/